# Getting Line number of code executed

Tags: java

I am writing an application for automated generation of unit test cases.The application takes as input a .java file and then process's it to find all its methods. The methods are then invoked using test data using the following command.
       method.invoke(classObj,MethodArg);
Now i wish to find the lines that were executed int the invoked method to calculate the coverage. I have tried doing this using StackTrace() but it gives the line number of my application code. 
Can anyone help me with this. I am completely and utterly lost. Any help will be highly appreciated.
My current code is:

```
    Runnable myRunnable;
    myRunnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
    try { 
      int returnValInt = (int) fm.invoke(fobj, fargs);
      System.out.println(new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());                                  
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
};
Thread th= new Thread(myRunnable, "th");
th.start();
```

Comment: `new Exception()` is created at a line within your code. So it will of course reference that line in your code. Is there any reason you are creating your own test framework and not using one of the standard ones, e.g. JUnit?

Comment: I doubt that's how code coverage is or can at all be accomplished. I think you probably want a VM agent to do some low-level tracing instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can read how coverage tools collect their stats [here](http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf).

But before that, what you're trying to do isn't going to be much use - the whole point of the any test is to test the intent of a piece of code.  To do this you need to know what the boundaries are, what you expect the results to be.

For example:

```
public class Math
{
  public static long add(long a, long b)
  {
    return a + b;
  } 

  public static long multiply(long a, long b)
  {
    return a * b;
  } 
}

public class MathTest
{
  @Test
  public void testAdd()
  {
    assertTrue(5, Math.add(2, 3));
  }

  @Test
  public void testMultiply()
  {
    assertTrue(6, Math.multiply(2, 3));
  }
}
```

You would be unable to generate a test for this code from the method signatures alone.  You would have to introduce test data, which could feasibly define which method it applies to, however in anything more than simple cases such as this the data would become the test case and all you've achieved is the introduction of an additional layer of complexity.

At the end of the day the unit test is your test data where the test specification can be defined perfectly well.